# Is there a way to set the dimensions of a paragraph in itext7?

Tags: java-11, itext7

Trying to set the height along with setting the rotation on a Paragraph object results in the following error:
`ERROR c.i.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer - Rotation was not correctly processed for ParagraphRenderer`
Also, the height is sent to infinity resulting in an apparently empty page which I'm not sure if it's the expected behavior or not.

If I don't set the height, the text shows up rotated (which is what I want). But my task is to place the text at certain coordinates with certain dimensions and rotation. The placement is fine, but not being able to set the height results in assigning the rotation points to the wrong values and in turn displacing the final position of the text.

```java
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(text);
paragraph.setHeight(height);
paragraph.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
paragraph.setProperty(ROTATION_POINT_X, x);
paragraph.setProperty(ROTATION_POINT_Y, y);
paragraph.setProperty(ROTATION_ANGLE, asFloat(toRadians(rotation))));
document.add(paragraph);
```

Setting the margins to 0 doesn't seem to have any influence either. The text looks to keep some sort of margin anyway.

So is there a way to control what the dimensions of the object displayed are? I could also settle for a way to make the rotation pivot from the center of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You should set both width and height at the same time for rotated objects.
Here is an example code:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello world");
paragraph.setWidth(200);
paragraph.setHeight(20);
paragraph.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.RED);
paragraph.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100);
paragraph.setProperty(ROTATION_POINT_X, paragraph.getWidth().getValue() / 2);
paragraph.setProperty(ROTATION_POINT_Y, paragraph.getHeight().getValue() / 2);
paragraph.setRotationAngle(Math.PI / 180 * 45);
document.add(paragraph);
```

Visual result:

[image: result]